# Access json value using JavaScript object notation

Tags: javascript, json

I am unable to access a json value

```
{"phone": [
{
    "@attributes": {
        "type": "cell",
        "ext": ""
    }
}, "(123) 456 7890", {
    "@attributes": {
        "type": "work",
        "ext": ""
    }
}
]}
```

using the following JavaScript: psudo

```
for each phone line ...

console.log(["@attributes"].type);
console.log(this); 
console.log(["@attributes"].ext);

... end for
```

I expected the following output:

```
cell
work (123) 456 7890
```

Comment: @diEcho.. sorry about the {} cut!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually your json structure is not perfect, so here is the solution for your desired output

```
var json = {"phone": [
{
    "@attributes": {
        "type": "cell",
        "ext": ""
    }
}, "(123) 456 7890", {
    "@attributes": {
        "type": "work",
        "ext": ""
    }
}
]};
 console.log(json['phone'][0]['@attributes'].type);
 console.log('<br/>'+json['phone'][1]);
 console.log('<br/>'+json['phone'][2]['@attributes'].type);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MkAdx/)

Answer (score 2):

since `phone` is an array, try this,

```
   for(var i=0;i<phone.length;i++)
     console.log(phone[i].["@attributes"].type);
```

Also surround your response with `{`, as it is currently an invalid json.

Comment: I'm trying to access the phone number. which is the 'value' of the 'this'.

Comment: `@` is not a valid character for an JavaScript identifier. You have to use the bracket notation and a string : `console.log(phone[i]["@attributes"].type)`

Comment: @tnt your json is invalid. After writing a proper json, validate it from jsonlint.com

Comment: @adeel the json comes from a php json_encode the origional xml is     <phone type="cell" ext=""></phone>
    <phone type="work" ext="">(123) 456 7890</phone>

Comment: its better if you write a custom json

Comment: @adeel are you saying that i am unable to access the value from JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't start any object, associative array key or well anything with a non-alphanumerical character.

Also you have 3 calls to console and only two lines of expected output? What does console.log(this) output?

Comment: Actually you can. Object *properties* (there is no such thing as a "associative array" in JavaScript) can be any string.

Comment: @dave thats what i'm trying to access it's the phone_number part of the json data.

Comment: @RoToRa I was just using the terminology. Aside from your JSON not being wrapped in {} I can't see console.log(this) working since this is out of scope unless you are running it through a loop.

Comment: @tnt I understand that but `this` will not evaluate to anything, you need to change either the XML that PHP is using to output so that you have a better output or manually create your JSON string and output that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `phone` array is quite messy because you have:

```
phone[0] === {'@attributes':...}
phone[1] === '(123) 456 7890'
phone[2] === {'@attributes':...}
```

Is that what you realy wanted to have there?

Comment: the json comes from a php json_encode the origional xml is <phone type="cell" ext=""></phone> <phone type="work" ext="">(123) 456 7890</phone>

Comment: hmm, so there should be some validation because you couldn't be sure on which index is the phone number or the object literal (attributes), am I right?

Comment: only simple loop here in your next question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203297/javascript-json-values/7203546#7203546