# JavaScript json values

Tags: javascript, json

Using JavaScript; how do I produce this output

```
cell
work (123) 456 7890
```

from this valid json

```
{"phone": [
{
    "@attributes": {
        "type": "cell",
        "ext": ""
    }
}, "(123) 456 7890", {
    "@attributes": {
        "type": "work",
        "ext": ""
    }
}
]}
```

Comment: Who created that abomination of a JSON document? It should be `[{"type": "cell"}, {"type": "work", "number":"(123) 456 7890"}]`. This looks to be automatically generated from an XML document. If that's the case, you should parse that XML instead.

Comment: @phihag php json_encode from <phone type="cell" ext=""></phone> <phone type="work" ext="">(123) 456 7890</phone>

Comment: @thilo everything.. cant access that phone number

Comment: http://www.json.org/js.html ... `phone` is an array. You want to access the second element. I don't see where the problem could be?

Comment: Actually, it looks like it might be VCard data that's been converted to XML and _then_ to JSON… if so, yaiks

Comment: @tnt You should really use the XML then. Goes like this (in pseudo-code): `for each (var phone in doc.getElementsByTagName("phone")) {output(phone.getAttribute("type") + " " + phone.text())}`. On a related note, please specify what kind of output you want. Is a string enough? HTML? JavaScript can be used in a web browser, a local GUI or CLI application, or even a [server](http://nodejs.org/).

Comment: @phihag surely switching to xml for the sake of a phone number is rather extreme. I have 50,000+ xml docs many gui widgets.

Comment: @tnt There must be a misunderstanding. If you have 50k XML docs, why do you use JSON? JSON is a format of itself and not a good way to access XML documents.

Comment: @phihag indeed, but is seems json is better suited to map to browser inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a very narrow sense, you'd need to do this

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

var type = jsonObj.phone[0]['@attributes'].type // "cell"
var phoneNumber = jsonObj.phone[1] // "(123) 456 7890"
```

But the structure of that JSON data may change, so you can't rely on the 0/1 indexes, and anyway the structure is weird. Like the comments say, if it comes from XML, then parse that instead

Answer (score 0):

I see you kind of duplicate question from:
[Access json value using JavaScript object notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202398/access-json-value-using-javascript-object-notation)
Simple loop could help:

```
var tel;
for (var i=0,l=phone.length; i<l; i++) {
  if (phone[i]['@attributes']) {
    if (phone[i-1] && typeof phone[i-1]==='string') {
      tel = phone[i-1];
    } else {
      tel = '';
    }
    console.log(phone[i]['@attributes'].type+' '+tel);
  }
```

But the guys above are right, if the structure changed a bit, this code will probably won't work.

Comment: sorry about the dupe, trying to get my head around the problem. thanks tho!